# Safe writing to variable in cython c wrapper within two python processes or distinct memory for python processes

Tags: memory-management, cython

I am creating a wrapper over c library that recieves some financial data and I want to collect it into python data type (dict with list of field names and list of lists with financial data fields).

On the c level there is function that starts "listening" to some port and when any event appears some user-defined function is called. This function is written in cython. Simplified example of such function is here:

```
cdef void default_listener(const event_data_t* data, int data_count, void* user_data):

    cdef trade_t* trades = <trade_t*>data # cast recieved data according to expected type 
    cdef dict py_data = <dict>user_data # cast user_data to initial type(dict in our case)

    for i in range(data_count):
        # append to list in the dict that we passed to the function 
        # fields of recieved struct
        py_data['data'].append([trades[i].price,
                                trades[i].size,
                                ]
                               )
```

The problem: when there is only one python process with this function started, there are no problems, but if I start another python process and run the same function one of the processes will be terminated in undetermiined amount of time. I suppose that this happens because two functions that are called simultaniously in different processes may try to write to the same part of the memory. May this be the case?

If this is the case, are there any ways to prevent two processes use the same memory? Or maybe some lock can be established before the cython code starts to write?

P.S.: I also have read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/#cpythons-memory-management) and according to it for each python process there is some memory allocated that does not intersect with parts for other processes. But it is unclear for me, is this allocated memory also available for underlying c functions or these functions have acces to another fields that may intersect

Comment: 1) How are you running the threads/processes? Python supports both "multithreading" and "mulitprocessing". "multithreading" shares memory, while "multiprocessing" doesn't, unless you specifically tell it to. 2) Python already has the "global interpreter lock" or GIL, which should stop two threads writing to the same memory at the same time - so I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: 3) One possible problem is that Cython doesn't release the GIL by itself (unless you tell it to specifically) so it can potentially lock out a separate Python thread. To comment on that we'd need to know how your listener function is set up/called. My guess is that this is your problem, but I don't have enough information to tell

Comment: In my code, there is neither multiprocessing, nor multithreading. All the logic is in the  c library, if it is crucial I'll find the exact part responsible for creating "listening" process. I can also provide the link to source code of c library on bitbucket if it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess at the answer based on your comment - if it's wrong then I'll delete it, but I think it's likely enough to be right to be worth posting as an answer.

Python has a locking mechanism known as the Global Interpreter Lock (or GIL). This ensures that multiple threads don't attempt to access the same memory simultaneously (including memory internal to Python, that may not be obvious to the user).

Your Cython code will be working on the assumption that its thread holds the GIL. I strongly suspect that this isn't true, and so performing *any* operations on a Python object will likely cause a crash. One way to deal with this would be to follow [this section of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) in the C code that calls the Cython code. However, I suspect it's easier to handle in Cython.

First tell Cython that the function is "`nogil`" - it does not require the GIL:

```
cdef void default_listener(const event_data_t* data, int data_count, void* user_data) nogil:
```

If you try to compile now it will fail, since you use Python types within the function. To fix this, claim the GIL within your Cython code.

```
cdef void default_listener(...) nogil:
    with gil:
        default_listener_impl(...)
```

What I've done is put the implementation in a separate function that *does* require the GIL (i.e. doesn't have a `nogil` attached). The reason for this is that you can't put `cdef` statements in the `with gil` section (as you say in your comment) - they have to be outside it. However, you can't put `cdef dict` outside it, because it's a Python object. Therefore a separate function is the easiest solution. The separate function looks almost exactly like `default_listener` does now.

---

It's worth knowing that this isn't a complete locking mechanism - it's really only to protect the Python internals from being corrupted - an ordinary Python thread will release and regain the GIL periodically automatically, and that may be while you're "during" an operation. Cython won't release the GIL unless you tell it to (in this case, at the end of the `with gil:` block) so does hold an exclusive lock during this time. If you need finer control of locking then you may want to look at either the `multithreading` library, or wrapping some C locking library.

Comment: As far as I understand, nogil should be set on function that starts a new thread, which is not `default_listener` but `attach_listener` with `default_listener` as a parameter. So should I add `nogil` to `attach_listener`, to `default_listener` or to both?

Comment: `nogil` on a function is simply saying that it doesn't need the GIL (when it's called). In this case it doesn't need the GIL because it immediately asks for the GIL itself. You definitely want to follow this pattern on `default_listener`. It's hard to know about `attach_listener` - are you calling it from C or Python? If you're calling it from C then it should probably be the same. If you're calling it from Python then it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications, they are really helpful. The last(I hope) problem I face is `cdef statement not allowed` in with gil statement

Comment: You're right - it doesn't work quite as written. I've made an edit to the answer that should solve it: put the implementation in a separate function (`default_listener_impl`), then have a wrapper function that simply acquires the GIL and calls the implementation.

Comment: I do not know what are the exact drawbacks but  simple assigning without type definition works for now: `py_data = <dict>user_data`

Comment: That should be fine too. Setting a type for things like `dict` or `list` rarely has much benefit in Cython

Comment: one more related question: now I want to copy var that I pass as user_data parameter and then clear it. This operations will be done in another cython extension module. The problem is that default listener is not supposed to be interrupted. How should I lock the variable passed as user_data to prevent it from writing while copying and clearing it?

Comment: That's actually surprisingly hard. A `with nogil` block should stop other Python threads from executing but it isn't reliable - if any interpreted Python code gets called (e.g. from a constructor) then that _can_ release the GIL. You probably want to use some sort of lock object (either from `multithreading`, or wrap your C library); however, you need to write your interface to enforce that. You can't just tell Python "lock this dict"

Comment: @IvanMishalkin Thinking about it though: a shallow copy (`dict.copy`) and emptying the dict (`dict.clear()`) within a nogil block should both execute without running any interpreted Python code. The shallow copy is just a bunch of `incref`s, while the clear might in principle execute destructors but won't because of the shallow copy, and even if it did it wouldn't matter because the dictionary's already clear. If that's all you're doing then you're probably OK without a lock (but there is a difference between me thinking something, and being certain)