# Define custom class in Cython cdef class

Tags: python, collections, cython

This question is related to my old one ([Safe writing to variable in cython c wrapper within two python processes or distinct memory for python processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805481/safe-writing-to-variable-in-cython-c-wrapper-within-two-python-processes-or-dist/57806961?noredirect=1#comment104316770_57806961))

I have custom class inherited from collections.deque with some additional logic:

```
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock

class DequeWithLock(deque):
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), maxlen=None):
        super().__init__(iterable, maxlen)
        self.lock = Lock()

    def safe_append(self, data):
        try:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.append(data)
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
```

I also have in some sort "main" cdef class named `SubscriptionClass`. The strange thing is that everything works fine if I write this class as following:

```
from dxpyfeed.wrapper.utils.data_class import DequeWithLock as deque

cdef class SubscriptionClass:
    cdef dict data

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()
        self.data['data'] = deque()
```

This code works as expected and even Lock() works as supposed to. However I'd like to get rid of unnecessary dict definition, so I rewrite to code in the following way:

```
cdef class SubscriptionClass:
    cdef object data

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = deque()
```

But this throws me a message every time a Cython-function started in another thread tries to use `SubscriptionClass.data` and no elements are appended to deque. The message: `Exception ignored in: 'path.to.cython.function'`.

I also tried to add `cdef dict __dict__` from ([Mixing cdef and regular python attributes in cdef class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632297/mixing-cdef-and-regular-python-attributes-in-cdef-class)) but this gives me dead kernel.

Comment: Where you get `Exception ignored` can you add `try: whatever_causes_the_exception(); except: traceback.print_exc(); raise`. That should at least tell you what the exception was that's been ignored

Comment: Thinking about it though - it might just be that `data` isn't public (Cython attributes aren't, by default) so your other thread can't access it. `cdef public object data`

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in `path.to.cython.function` so I got Exception ignored because of it

Comment: Has it been solved? I think @DavidW answer is accurate.